# jquery auto running a method

Tags: javascript, jquery

in jQuery how do I activate a method automatically rather than selecting an element when an if..else statement is ran? For example:

```
if(data.session_state == false) {
   RatherThanSelectingAutoRunProccess.fancybox();
```

Comment: Rather than doing a selection using $("#select").fancybox(); .... the script auto activates the fancybox plugin. Idk how better to explain it.

Comment: i think your a little confused about how jquery and fancybox work.  do you want the fancybox to popup automatically?

Comment: @Patricia: Yes.. and I might be lol.

Comment: and what content did you want to go in it?  you can trigger the click of whatever the fancybox is wired up to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea: **side effects**!

```
var data = {
  session_state: function() {
    $("#select").fancybox();
    return true;
  }
};

if(data.session_state() == true) { // fancybox is called
  // do some other stuff
}
```

Note that `session_state` is now a function.

Also note that I would immediately fire a developer who wrote this in my project :-)

Comment: So how would I go about activating a plugin without using an event or a selector?

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby: your question seems totally crazy to me. I probably don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean when the page loads?

```
$(function() {
     RatherThanSelectingAutoRunProccess.fancybox();
});
```

Comment: No, I need it to autorun if data.session_state == false.

Answer (score 0):

here you can make use of `setInterval`

```
setInterval(function(){
   if(data.session_state == false) {
      RatherThanSelectingAutoRunProccess.fancybox();
},100);
```

Every 100 msec, it will check for the condition. and if true call the method.

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery's trigger() method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fancybox-div").fancybox({
        type: 'image',
        href: 'image.jpg'    //Or whatever kind of data you're loading
    });
    //Here is how you trigger the fancybox
    if(data.session_state == false) {
       $("#fancybox-div").trigger("click");
    }
});
```